# Регулярные выражения проверка введенных данных

Tags: javascript, html

нужна ваша помощь в написании корректных выражений

1. проверка на наличие "@" и "." (/[@][.]/) это мой вариант в котором я не уверен
2. проверка номера телефона, должен состоять из 14 символов и начинаться на +48 (так же даю свой вариант /^+[48[0-9]{14}$]/) мой вариант не работает знаю что можно использовать вместо [0-9] - \d но не понимаю как его туда впихнуть

Comment: Во-первых, в вопросе должен быть один вопрос, а не два. Во-вторых, а в чём собственно вопрос? Эти варианты ведут себя как-то не так или в чём проблема?

Comment: Почему вы решили, что ваши варианты не рабочие?

Comment: @andreymal
я указал что мои варианты не рабочие, + вопрос был в корректном написании. Если как-то не правильно написал, извините я еще новичек во всем.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> нужна ваша помощь в написании корректных выражений

Предложу такой вариант

```js
// проверка на наличие "@" и "."
let re = /@|\./
console.log(re.test('123.456'))
console.log(re.test('my@mail.ru'))

// проверка номера телефона, должен состоять из 14 символов и начинаться на +48
re = /^\+48\d{14}$/
console.log(re.test('+4812345678901234'))
console.log(re.test('+48123456'))
```

> номера телефона, должен состоять из 14 символов и начинаться на +48

Дюже длинный номер... Если что - нужно просто уменьшить циферку в `{}` скобках.

Comment: /@|\./ , если не ошибаюсь | обозначает или , а как сделать без или , что б два четких условия было

Comment: Так на один символ короче. :) Но можно написать и вот так `/[@\.]/`.